# Postfix, read/process email content

Tags: email, email-server, postfix

Here's a use case for my application. All incoming emails to different email addresses have to be processed by reading the content of email messages, along with the information such as: from email address, subject line and date/time sent. This information later has to be HTTP POSTed to a web service API or stored in a DB.

We are thinking about using PostFix as our MTA software. Using PostFix, is it possible to implement such a process to read emails? If yes please explain how? Or are there any programs that are readily available to read emails and store in a DB from PostFix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible with Postfix itself. As you said it is a MTA where T stands for transport. It is not a mail processing agent. But you can configure different MDAs (mail delivery agents).

You can do this with [procmail](http://www.procmail.org) for example or any other program that accepts mail via STDIN. These programs can be included into Postfix with the [pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) configuration options. See the manual for details and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes postfix email server has the notion of a content_filter

```
cat /etc/postfix/master.cf
```

to which I added

```
filter  unix  -  n  n  -  -  pipe
    flags=Rq  user=ehookfilter  argv=/usr/local/bin/content_filter.sh
    -f ${sender}  --  ${recipient}
```

So each incoming email received by postfix server will execute my script ( my app is b2b so low traffic this can be converted to a daemon if need be )

```
/usr/local/bin/content_filter.sh
```

which is loosely based on http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html

above shell `content_filter.sh` in turn executes my below referenced golang code `smtp_filter` which does the heavy lifting of parsing email headers + body ... then I have my go code iterate across all attachments ...  it persists by making REST calls into our in house workflow

/usr/local/bin/smtp_filter ${curr_output_file_prefix}  < in.$$ >> $curr_amalgamated_file

to gain appreciation of what my 900 lines of golang does here are the libraries it pulls in

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/mail"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "github.com/google/go-github/github"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "net/http"
    "regexp"

    "github.com/jaytaylor/html2text"
    "mime"
    "mime/multipart"
    "mime/quotedprintable"
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/base64"
)
```

needless to say this is not cookie cutter yet I had no prior expertise on SMTP ... I am thinking of posting a full writeup of this solution if demands warrants ...  a big benefit of writing code to read email is this shunts to ground incoming email malware vectors as we no longer had to read email ;-)